# Android Room Database + JUnit5 Test

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, android-room, junit5

I'm trying to test my Room database using JUnit5 (I cannot use JUnit4). This is my test class:

```
class DatabaseTest {
    // Get references to the Database and GendersDao class.
    private lateinit var db: Database
    private lateinit var gendersDao: GendersDao

    @BeforeEach
    fun createDb() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, Database::class.java).build()
        gendersDao = db.getGendersDao()
    }

    @AfterEach
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }

    // Create a test function and annotate it with @Test.
    // Here we are first adding an item to the db and then checking if that item
    // is present in the db. If the item is present then our test cases pass.
    @Test
    fun writeAndReadGender() = runBlocking {
        val gender = Genders(0, "M", "Male")
        gendersDao.insert(gender)
        val byGender = gendersDao.findByGenderCode(listOf("M"))
        assertEquals(/* expected = */ gender, /* actual = */ byGender[0])
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I get this error message:

> No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

My **build.gradle** contains:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
    classpath "de.mannodermaus.gradle.plugins:android-junit5:1.8.2.1"
}
```

My app level **build.gradle** contains:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2"
    androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2"
    ...
}
```

I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664793/android-junit5-no-instrumentation-registered-when-getting-context), but it looks like the user didn't find a solution as well. It looks like the culprit is this like, but I can't understand how to fix the issue:

```
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: Room depends on the Android SDK, cannot be run as unit test. You need to run it as instrumentation test. In any case here you're technically testing the Room library itself, which imho is not what you should be aiming for.

Comment: @m0skit0, thanks for the heads-up! I was trying to follow this training lesson: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db

Comment: Ok I see, I've never tested Room using the SQLite support libraries, so I can't help further, sorry.